# nginx reverse proxy not returning website

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

### The setup

Currently, we have an Apache2 webserver acting as load balancer for our web architecture. The backends are Xen virtual machines accessible via IPv6 for the public Internet and via IPv4 for our VPN. The problem is that the Apache 2 loadbalancer doesn't perform as well as we would like it to so we're switching to nginx.

### The configuration

The version of nginx installed is 1.3.10 which was compiled with standard Debian options. We had to go for this version because it was the only one that supports IPv6 backends which is a requirement for these VMs. For the moment, nginx only has one "virtual host" or server block and it is the following.

```
upstream backend-cookissime-prod  {
  server cookissime-prod.cookissime1.vm.cob:80 max_fails=5;
  server cookissime-prod.cookissime2.vm.cob:80 max_fails=5;
}

server {
  listen 37.59.6.220:80;
#  listen [::]:80;
  server_name www.cookissime.fr;

  access_log  /var/log/nginx/cookissime-prod.log;
  error_log  /var/log/nginx/cookissime-prod.log;

  ## send request back to apache1 ##
  location / {
    proxy_pass  http://backend-cookissime-prod;
    proxy_next_upstream error timeout invalid_header http_500 http_502 http_503 http_504;
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_buffering off;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
   }
}

upstream backend-cookissime-dev  {
  server cookissime-dev.cookissime1.vm.cob:80 max_fails=5;
  server cookissime-dev.cookissime2.vm.cob:80 max_fails=5;
}
```

There is also a second code block which takes the above information and replaces prod with dev. The domain names cookissime-prod.cookissime1.vm.cob and cookissime-prod.cookissime2.vm.cob resolve to an IPv6 on our internal DNS.

### The problem

The above configuration seems to be good syntax-wise. The problem is that most of the time, this configuration displays the default "Welcome to nginx" page but sporadically it will display the website for a few minutes then return to the default page.

This very setup works correctly with Apache2 so the virtual machines are functionnal.

What am I missing ? What could cause these problems ?

Comment: Anything in the error log?

Comment: Nope. Error logs empty :/

Comment: Try setting a different `root` within that `server` block (so that you don't get the "Welcome to nginx page") to verify that you're hitting the right server and vhost.

Comment: That doesn't change anything. But I know I hit the right server because the access logs got to the right place.

Comment: Given that your syntax does indeed seem to be correct, I would check that you are indeed always requesting the specified `server_name`- that is to say, are you always testing to `http://www.cookissime.fr` or at some points have you been testing only to `http://cookissime.fr` which happens to have the same DNS entry as the www subdomain?